# hybridauth - can not restore google login

Tags: hybridauth

I have made login script with HybridAuth. I'm loged in my website with "providers" Facebook, Google, Twitter. When PHP sessions time out, I want to restore my connected "providers".

I use this code :

```
    $connected_adapters_list = $hybridauth->getConnectedProviders(); 
          if( count( $connected_adapters_list ) ){
                foreach( $connected_adapters_list as $adapter_id ){
                    echo  $adapter_id . "<br>";
          }
    }
```

HybridAuth can restore my Facebook and Twitter connection, but not Google. This is code error output. How to solve it ?

```
Ooophs, we got an error: User profile request failed! Google returned an invalid response:stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'errors' => array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'domain' => 'global', 'reason' => 'authError', 'message' => 'Invalid Credentials', 'locationType' => 'header', 'location' => 'Authorization', )), ), 'code' => 401, 'message' => 'Invalid Credentials', )), )) Error code: 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also has this problem,

it could be sloved by using "logoutAllProviders()" function

there is code :

```
   try{
       $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );

        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Google" );
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

   }
   catch( Exception $e ){
        $hybridauth->logoutAllProviders();
        $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth( $config );          
        $adapter = $hybridauth->authenticate( "Google" );
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
   }
}
```

good luck for you !